# What is the syntax that creates a hyperlink to the xy position of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

What I'm trying to do is to create a link on the same page to a java applet link for which I don't have the parameters.   Take a look at any of the chessboards at Chesscalisthenics.com

Comment: @ggg: Did you know that you're supposed to mark good answers to your previous questions as "accepted answers"? Please go back to your old questions before asking more.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "link" to xy positions, but from Javascript you could use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.scrollTo).

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported directly in HTML. There is a workaround: Add the xy position as a query parameter to the URL (like `...?x=...&y=...`) and add an `inClick` handler to the link. The handler can examine the URL (`this.href`) to get the position.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you can't. But you can fake it - add the x,y as GET variables in the URL query string, like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/yourpage.htm?x=50&y=50&target=divID
```

In your javascript, you'd use something like [window.scrollTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) to jump to those coordinates, which you can [pull from the query string](http://www.zrinity.com/developers/code_samples/code.cfm/CodeID/59/JavaScript/Get_Query_String_variables_in_JavaScript).

Make sense?

Comment: PS - document.getElementByID() and pass in the target parameter from the URL too, obviously.